# Regular Expression to replace Unicode between opening & closing tag

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need fastest method to replace unicode symbols from a string which is next to the '<' or '> tags

For example,  input string:

```
<एक्सएम्ेल type = "ए"> क्सएम् </एक्सएम्ेल>
```

Expected output :

```
 <REPLACED type = "ए"> क्सएम् </REPLACED>`
```

Values  inside the tag or value of type element should not be replaced, only the tag name should be replaced

This is the code i tried & is not working

```
private static Regex _compiledUnicodeRegex = new Regex(@"<[^\u0000-\u007F]", RegexOptions.Compiled);



    public static String StripUnicodeCharactersFromString(string inputValue)
    {
        return _compiledUnicodeRegex.Replace(inputValue, "REPLACED");
    }
```

Note -

1. The unicode values are may not be same always
2. String may not be in XML format always, so i should match opening tag or closing tag only
3. I need a regular expression syntax to check whether string right after < is a unicode or string which left to the > is unicode

Comment: You have asked this question before. Regex is notoriously bad at this sort of thing, its for *regular expressions* not *markup languages*, is there any chance you could parse this using a dedicated xml parser?

Comment: There is no way to parse this as xml, Previous question was by closed by someone stating this is possible duplicate of some other question, But the string is not a XML string, Only the thing i need is to verify whether string is unicode after a < tag

Comment: hrm maybe `(?<=\<)[^/\u0000-\u007F]+|(?<=\</)[^\u0000-\u007F]+`

Comment: Ok, so we can assume that this is not about html/xml, so once a solution is provided, you won't come back with questions how to exclude text inside some `CDATA` section, how to only replace specific matching open- and close tags instead of all text occurences, ...? And even though your title mentions regex, you actually want a fast (performance wise) text manipulation technique, whether it is regex or something different?

Comment: Fun fact: in a C# internal string, everything is unicode. However, not every single char is unicode, since some rare symbols are represented by multiple chars. So if I understand you correctly, you generally want to replace all text without any exception after the first `<` or before the last `>` in your text? However, your description does not align with your examples. Clarify please.

Comment: As i mentioned the example above, the one who have common sense should understand what i am searching for and TheGeneral already gave me the solution i wanted, I am sorry for you grek40

Comment: @Gulikz the computer has no common sense. So, as long as you rely on common sense, you will always rely on other people to help you with technical problems. Only when you start thinking and communicating with precision, you can solve such problems yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace a streak of text that consists of non-ASCII chars, only after `<` or `</`, and this is a problem that *can* be solved with regular expressions.

You may use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=</?)[^\x00-\x7F]+", "REPLACED");
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%3C%2F%3F%29%5B%5E%5Cx00-%5Cx7F%5D%2B&i=%3C%E0%A4%8F%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%8F%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B2%20type%20%3D%20%22%E0%A4%8F%22%3E%20%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%8F%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D%20%3C%2F%E0%A4%8F%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%8F%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B2%3E&r=REPLACED) (note it allows infinite width lookbehind patterns).

The regex matches

- `(?<=</?)` - (a positive lookbehind) a location in the string that is preceded by `<` or `</` (in other words, that is preceded with `<` that may or may not be followed with `/`)
- `[^\x00-\x7F]+` - 1 or more chars other than those in the ASCII set.

Comment: Ahh this looks better, I was hiding behind the door when they were handing out regex skills

Comment: What about self closing tags, ie. <एक्सएम्ेल/> ?

Comment: @Gulikz I think it [still fits](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%3c%2f%3f%29%5b%5e%5cx00-%5cx7F%5d%2b&i=%3c%e0%a4%8f%e0%a4%95%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%8f%e0%a4%ae%e0%a5%8d%e0%a5%87%e0%a4%b2+type+%3d+%22%e0%a4%8f%22%3e+%e0%a4%95%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%8f%e0%a4%ae%e0%a5%8d+%3c%2f%e0%a4%8f%e0%a4%95%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%8f%e0%a4%ae%e0%a5%8d%e0%a5%87%e0%a4%b2%3e%0d%0a%3c%e0%a4%8f%e0%a4%95%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%8f%e0%a4%ae%e0%a5%8d%e0%a5%87%e0%a4%b2%2f%3e&r=REPLACED) the current requirements.